# Use of were or have been

Tags: grammar, past-tense, present-perfect

Which sentence is grammatically correct?

> There **were** no rains for a long time.

Or

> There **have been** no rains for a long time.

Comment: Why do you think that one of them is incorrect?

Answer (score 2):

Both. The first would be used if you were describing the state of a land in the past. The second sentence would be used if you were talking about the past up to the present. Usually we don't count rain, so we might say,

> There was no rain for a long time.

or

> There has been no rain for a long time.

Comment: Would be nice to add a note about why we might consider a rain to be countable (mostly, distinct events of rainfall, especially for farmers or others that are very interested in exact details of weather).